# C# Mock the object and expect its constructor to return mocked object using Rhino Mocks

Tags: c#, unit-testing, rhino-mocks

I have an object which I initialize inside using block to dispose few things. Then later inside using block I am calling some method of that object.

```
public void MyMethod()
{
 using(var obj = new Someclass())
 {
   // I want to mock this method call
   var result = obj.SomeMethod();
 }
}
```

As I am writing unit test case for this, I have to mock the object and expect my own result by calling SomeMethod.

I understand that If you want to mock any object then that object should be passed as a dependency and then we can expect our own result there but here in this case, if I pass the object as a dependency then I will not be able to use using block. For eg-

```
public void MyMethod(SomeClass object)
{
 // Here can I do something like this ?
 // If this works then I can easily send the mocked object
 using(var obj = object)
 {
   // I want to mock this method call
   var result = obj.SomeMethod();
 }     
}
```

So my question is that

1. Is there a way that I pass the mock object as a dependency and also use the object initialization but I should expect from my object that If your constructor is called anywhere in the code then please ignore that
2. Shall I stop thinking of using Using block and call the dispose method manually

Thanks in advance

Comment: You will have to construct the object using the mocking framework. The constructor will return the actual object. Instead of passing in an object, pass in a way for the target to construct the object, such as `Func<T>`. Additionally, if you want to inject this as a dependency the target should no longer *be* responsible for disposing it, this should fall to the code on the outside. You can also pass in a factory that returns disposable objects. There's lots of ways to do this without trying to mock the constructor (which you can't).

Comment: When injecting a dependency, you not only redirect the responsability for *creating*, but also for *disposing* the instance. So either do both, or none. You can´t expect your instance to change it´s impolementation at runtime.

Comment: @Lasse Vågsæther Karlsen, I am constructing the object using mocking framework and then passing as a dependency but when my using block executes, then It overrides my mocked object and initialize it with actual object because of the new operator there. I want to understand if I can stop that constructor to override my mocked object

Comment: You won´t need to *create* the instance *in* your method, but *outside*.

Comment: I would have thought that either MyClass has dependencies in which case its the dependencies that you mock and inject into MyClass.... or MyClass is an implementation of some interface in which case it needs mocking and injecting into its consuming class.

Comment: I'm not sure you'd want to extend the scope of SomeClass instance just for the sake of mocking, and wouldn't avoid the Using block just for that... If it makes sense from your design perspective - sure, but mocking may be a "code smell": https://medium.com/javascript-scene/mocking-is-a-code-smell-944a70c90a6a

Answer (score 0):

When adding the depency as parameter to your method, the client of that method isn´t only resposible for *creating* that depenency, but also for *disposing* it. Thus there´s no need to have the `using` *in* your method. However you´ll need it at the client-side:

```
using(var mock = Mock<MyClass>()) // don´t know the exact Rhino-syntax to get a mock
{
    MyMethod(mock);
}
```

Now your method becomes something like this:

```
void MyMethod(MyClass m)
{
    m.SomeMethod();  // notice that there´s no using
}
```

However when having a mock you surely won´t need to dipsoe it at all, at it is a leightweight instance whithout any unmanaged resources.

EDIT: If you are sure that `MyMethod` is the only place that uses the dependency, you can surely dispose it within that method as well:

```
void MyMethod(MyClass m)
{
    using(m) { m.SomeMethod(); }
}
```

However thais may lead to confusion to clients of `MyMethod`, as the dependecy will be disposed after calling this method:

```
var m = Mock<MyClass>();
MyMethod(m);
m.DoSomething();  // will lead to ObjectDisposedException
```

Comment: I may be bad in framing the question but I have tried to modify the question to give some more context. Please have a relook

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to do this. You want to pass dependency, but only for creation of the object. This way you can mock `Dispose` assuring you never dispose the object in tests. I don't have knowledge of rhino mock library, but you should get the idea.

You need `SomeClassFactory` which will be dependency and will return an instance of `SomeClass`. This way you can mock `SomeClass`'s `Dispose` method and ignore disposing the object.

```
//Arrange
var someClassFactoryMock = MockRepository.GenerateMock<ISomeClassFactory>();
var someClassMock = MockRepository.GenerateMock<ISomeClass>();
someClassMock.Stub(s => s.Dispose()); // Ignore Dispose
someClassFactoryMock.Stub(s => s.Get()).Return(someClassMock); // Return mock
var fooClass = new Foo();
fooClass.SomeClassFactory = someClassFactoryMock;

// Act
fooClass.SomeMethod();

// Assert
someClassMock.Expect(s => s.SomeMethod()).Repeat.Times(1); // Assert that it was called once.
```

SomeClassFactory is just a very simple factory

```
public class SomeClassFactory : ISomeClassFactory
{
    public ISomeClass Get() => new SomeClass();
}
```

And put it all together:

```
public class Foo
{
    public ISomeClassFactory SomeClassFactory { get; set; }
    public void MyMethod()
    {
        using(ISomeClass obj = SomeClassFactory.Get())
        {
          // When testing, obj will be a mock with Dispose method mocked to not do anything. This way it will not be disposed.
           var result = obj.SomeMethod();
        }
    }
}
```

Please note this is only pseudo code. If you want any errors, please let me know.